# Difference `ajax:send` event and `click` event that send ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript

I'm using ajax request with `coffee` in rails like this.

```
  $('#reload').on(
    'click': -> $('#response').html "<div class='panel'><img src='assets/load.gif'/></div>"
    'ajax:success': (data, res, xhr) ->
      $('#response').html res
  )
```

This code works fine, but when I change the `click` event to `ajax:send` event (I thought it represents more properly what I'm doing.), then the code works little different.

The `panel` appears just after clicking, but the load image appears only after 2 or 3 seconds.
I'm going to use in this time `click` event as before. But I want to know why it happens to avoid my future mistake.

Comment: Well, they're two different events. They get triggered at different points in time during the code execution. It's expected for them to be slightly different.

Comment: I agree, using `ajax:send` seems more logical. It seems odd that there would be a delay loading load.gif, which is not explained by the different times at which `ajax:send` and `click` are triggered. Does that happen consistently?

Comment: Yes, I encountered this by using mac and I confirmed that happens also in ubuntu environment. But I found that cause of this delay of appearance related to somehow turbolinks behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The delay of appearance of image happens because I used turbolinks in wrong way.

My whole code was like this.

```
$ ->
  $('#reload').on(
    'ajax:send': -> $('#response').html "<div class='panel'><img src='assets/load.gif'/></div>"
    'ajax:success': (data, res, xhr) ->
      $('#response').html res
  )
```

and I rewrote `$ ->` to `ready = ->` and added this code, then the delay doesn't happens anymore.

```
$(document).ready(ready)
$(document).on('page:load', ready)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use ajax:before

```
$('#reload').bind('ajax:before', function() {
   $('#response').html("<div class='panel'><img src='assets/load.gif'/></div>"); 
});
```